# Reading and writing from/to InfluxDB

Tags: python, influxdb

Influxdb X contains sensor data and updated daily.
I am reading raw data from influxdb X (based on sensor-id), correcting them, then storing the updated data in influxdb Y—all that using python. The processes should be repeated with every new data uploaded to influxdb X. Is there a way to automate the operations with any new data entering the influxdb X?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say correctly what to do without understanding how your correction process looks and what InfluxDB version is there. But overall this looks like some kind of manual data replication which can be done with some tools like InfluxDB Relay https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-relay (for v1)

As for correction - depending on how it works it could be also a telegraf set up with InfluxDB listener as input https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/influxdb_listener , some processor plugin https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf#processor-plugins (could also be your own plugin for telegraf) and InfluxDB output.

If you're using version 2 there's a task concept for tasks which can be scheduled and seem to be what you want https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/process-data/